# Second moment of Silverman kernel

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, density-function, moment-problem

I am learning kernel smoothing method, in the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) , I find that second moment of  Silverman kernel is equal to zero (i.e $\int u^{2} K(u) d u$), I am not sure how to derive this result, that integral look difficult to compute,  it suffices to show that $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-x / \sqrt{2}} \sin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) d x=0
$$
(Actually this equal to zero when I use WolframAlpha to verify), can any body help to solve this integral, original integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2} \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{2}}} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)dx=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

First let us substitute $y=x/\sqrt 2$. Then we have to show
$$
J:=
\int_0^\infty
y^2\; e^{-y}\; (\sin y + \cos y)\; dy =0\ .
$$
We use partial integration to reduce the degree of the polynomial $y^2$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
J
&=
\int_0^\infty
y^2\; e^{-y}\; (\sin y + \cos y)\; dy 
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty
y^2\; (-e^{-y}\; \cos y)'\; dy 
\\
&=
-\Big[
y^2\; e^{-y}\; \cos y
\Big]_0^\infty
+
\int_0^\infty
(y^2)'\; e^{-y}\; \cos y\; dy 
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty
2y\; e^{-y}\; \cos y\; dy 
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty
y\; (e^{-y}\; (\sin y-\cos y))'\; dy 
\\
&=
\Big[
y\; e^{-y}\; (\sin y-\cos y)\Big]_0^\infty 
-
\int_0^\infty
y'\; e^{-y}\; (\sin y-\cos y)\; dy 
\\
&=
-
\int_0^\infty
e^{-y}\; (\sin y-\cos y)\; dy 
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty
(e^{-y}\; \sin y)'\; dy 
\\
&=
\Big[
e^{-y}\; \sin y\Big]_0^\infty 
\\
&=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$